# magento hide buy now button if stock level = 0

Tags: php, magento

We have a custom attribute that our previous developer (recently disappeared) has created in the magento admin area. This is a getIn_stock attribute which is reading from the point of sale system to check stock levels. It is returning either a 1 (in stock) or a 0 (out of stock). I have been digging around to see how I can display different content based on the output of this attribute. I found a thread that was based on the product price equaling 0 and tried to use it on the getIn_stock attribute but no luck. The following displays 'In Stock' even if the attribute returns a value of 0.

```
<?php if($_product->getIn_stock==0): ?>
                <?php echo 'Out of stock'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p>In Stock</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any advice would be a great help. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What does `var_dump($_product->getIn_stock);` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `var_dump($_product->getIn_stock);` right before your `if()` clause and see what actual value is in the property.

Comment: <?php var_dump($_product->getIn_stock); ?> outputs NULL on all products BUT <?php echo $_product->getIn_stock(); ?> displays a 0 on out of stock items and 1 on in stock items.

Comment: `$_product->getIn_stock` or `$_product->getIn_stock()`?? Btw, just change to `if (!$_product->getIn_stock()):`

Comment: Shouldn't it be in camel case? `$_product->getInStock()`

Comment: @clockworkgeek: to be honest - i've no idea ;-) thanks god i never worked with magento ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you point me in a good direction of a php resource that can help me learn in this context. Most of the sites I have found are extremely difficult to follow.

Comment: In what context? `!` operator and `var_dump()` are the basic instructions in php and well described in documentation.